# Lookup operation gives no result

Tags: excel, vba

The following code to matches a value from sheet A with sheet B, in a manner similar to Excel's `VLOOKUP` function.

The code runs without error but I get no result in the cells. How can I fix this?

```
Sub LoopTem()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim lastRow1 As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Proactive Template")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("To")

lastRow1 = ws.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow1
    For r = 2 To lastRow2
        If ws.Cells(i, 18) = ws2.Cells(r, 17) Then
           ws.Cells(i, 20) = ws2.Cells(r, 19)
        Else
           ws.Cells(i, 20) = ""
        End If
    Next r

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: One question per question, please. I edited out the second one. Feel free to post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François Corbett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have found the match, then you have to move on to the next cell in column 20. Right now you're not doing that; so regardless of whether a match is found, the search continues and the cell eventually gets overwritten by `ws.Cells(i, 20) = ""`.

To stop the search when you've found a match, use `Exit For`.

```
    If ws.Cells(i, 18) = ws2.Cells(r, 17) Then
       ws.Cells(i, 20) = ws2.Cells(r, 19)
       Exit For ' <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Stop search, iterate to next cell
    Else
       ws.Cells(i, 20) = "" ' <~~~~~~~~ Otherwise this will overwrite it eventually
    End If
```